# Android : using same Layout for EDIT and ADD NEW - Error in ADD?

Tags: android

I am using the same Layout and Activity for EDIT and ADD functionality.
I have activity A - this has a table with values. If i click on a ROW, it fetches the values and goes to Activity B and displays it in the fields there.
In the same activity A, i also have a ADD NEW button, on click of this, i go to Activity B, where i disaply the same layout with blank values for the user to input.

The EDIT part is working properly, but the ADD new is not. It gives me NULL Pointer error.

Activity B code

```
BankName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bankNameLabel);
BalanceAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.balanceLabel);
currencySpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.currencySpinner);

BankName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("bank"));
BalanceAmount.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("amount", 0)+"");
```

the setText is when i have values from the EDIT functionality.
Why is the BLANK screen during the ADD part not working?

Comment: downvoted for not posting the stacktrace (and probably for not even reading it, as it is obvious the error comes from getIntent().getExtras() that is null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in `onCreate()` method of your activity file to get data from intent.

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
String mBankName = bdl.getString("bank");
int mAmount = bdl.getInt("amount");

BankName.setText(mBankName);
BalanceAmount.setText(String.valueOf(mAmount));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
BankName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("bank"));
BalanceAmount.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("amount", 0)+"");
```

give checks like

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("bank"))
      BankName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("bank");
if(getIntent().hasExtra("amount"))
      BalanceAmount.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("amount",0)+"");
```

Comment: downvoted for total misunderstanding. getIntent() is not null, as an activity is always called with an intent (unless this is called before onCreate, which would failed before that, as setContentView couldn't have had been called.

Comment: undownvoted for changing getExtras().getString() to getStringExtra(), which should behave better, and remove the npe